# Rails 3: Include specific associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have some problems with the eager loading functionality:

Having the following (simplified) associations

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :alleys
end
```

and

```
class Alley < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reservations
end
```

I want to include reservations to alleys which have a specific property (in this case I want to load all reservations for a given date per alley).

Something like

```
Alley.includes(:reservations).where("reservations.date = ?", Date.today)
```

but this filters all the alley which don't have valid reservations.

Is there any way to apply a filter to the include mechanism in order to "fill" the association an_alley.reservations for every alley (even for those without valid reservations).

I sadly removed all my previous attempts to achieve this which i mainly found here, but I did try to Left Outer Join my alleys table with the reservations table which obviously resulted in getting multiple entries for each alley.

Any piece of advise or references would help me.

Thanks in advance.